# react native stack navigation header not visible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have a stack navigation with some screen i want the header to be hidden in some screen and i achieved that but i have a registration page that i want the header to be visible and to have the back button but its not visible,this is my navigation code

```
     <NavigationContainer>
       <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} 
                        initialParams={{title:null}} options={{
                                                           headerShown: false,
                                                           headerLeft: null,
                                                           gestureEnabled: false}} 
         />
         <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen}/>
       </Stack.Navigator>
     </NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)**  First remove header for entire stack navigator

*Choose one of them*

**I-way**
`<Stack.Navigator headerMode={'none'}>`

**II-way**
`<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}/>`

**2)** Then show header inside individual screen that you want

`<Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} options={{ headerShown: true}}/>`